# Change SE Linux context label of a specific folder inside a cifs mount

Tags: selinux

have cifs mount on my setup mounted via /etc/fstab with context set to **system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0**. There are **some specific folders** that I want to **override default context to set public_content_t** so I can share those folders between httpd and cifs processes.

1) I don't want mount entire mount point with public_content_t.

2) I don't want to set SE bool to make httpd access cifs.

I tried overriding semanage fcontext and chcon and tried many things for days now. It seems like SE Linux capability is run out to make the change satisfying

Comment: Could you mount the sub-directory separately with `context` mount option?

Comment: @sebasth Well there are multiple folders in that mount. So looking for other options.

Comment: What happens when you `chcon`?

Comment: @TimothyPulliam It gives me error saying _Operation not supported_